# Modbus TCP connection fail

Tags: javascript, node.js, modbus, plc, modbus-tcp

the master plc I use is "Panasonic FP7", and I have their official software "FPWIN GR7" so that I can use the PC to see the data flow, but the software lake of the function so I want to create one using nodeJS, there is my code :

master plc address: 192.168.50.30
port:502

PC:192.168.50.138

```
const Modbus = require('jsmodbus')
const net = require('net')
const socket = new net.Socket()
const netServer = new net.Server()
const server = new Modbus.server.TCP(netServer)



const options = {
'host' : "192.168.50.30",
'port' : "502"
}

const client = new Modbus.client.TCP(socket)

var myData;

socket.on("connect",function(){
    function getData(){
        client.readHoldingRegisters(0,1)
        .then((resp)=>{
            console.log(resp.response)
            socket.end()
        }).catch((err)=>{
            console.log(err)
      
        })
        socket.end()
    }
    setInterval(getData,500)
 })


socket.on("error",console.error)

socket.connect(options)
```

the error code I couldn't figure out:

```
UserRequestError {
  err: 'Offline',
  message: 'no connection to modbus server',
  response: undefined
}
```

[my struct](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qXAMy.jpg)

Comment: What is the purpose of defining `server`? (it does not seem to be used). Have you confirmed that the PLC is accessible on port 502? (I'd suggest using a known good application to confirm this e.g. [modpoll](https://www.modbusdriver.com/modpoll.html)/[mbpoll](https://github.com/epsilonrt/mbpoll)). Note that you are using JavaScript, not Java, so please correct the tags.

Comment: If your PLC acts as a Modbus master you cannot connect to it since it does not have port 502 listening for connections, it is not a Modbus server but a Modbus client. In Modbus, Master = Client and Slave = Server

Comment: @from56 that makes sense, I will try to connect as a client.

Comment: @Brits sry about wong tag, I will try using that application.

Comment: Your code already tries to connect as a client to the PLC, but that is not possible since your PLC is also a client, not a server.
Two clients cannot connect each other.
You could try to connect to one of your slaves from the PC, this should work, if they are both on the same subnet

Answer (score 0):

After seeing "from56" advice, I go Panasonic download every PLC documentation looking for TCP/IP setting, and I realize that my DHCP setting was wrong after fixing it, and then add a new "user connection information setting13" -> open type -> server connection.

Comment: DHCP has nothing to do with what you want to do.
Even if you manage to connect to the PLC, you will not see the traffic between the PLC as Modbus master and its Modbus slaves because they are other connections that do not pass through the PC. What you are trying to do is not possible.